# How do I deserialize a JSON string in a http response field in SpringBoot application?

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I receive the following response from an API:

```
{
 "id" : 1
 "name": name
 "body": JSONstring
}
```

I can map it to a Java POJO directly using restTemplate.exchange(url, method, null, model.class) if my model is as follows:

```
class Model {
  int id;
  String name;
  String body;
}
```

However, I want to also deserialize the JSON string in body into an object and achieve the following model:

```
class Model {
  int id;
  String name;
  Object body;
}
```

I get the following error currently:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the tests with the following class and everything worked just fine. The Json String in your example is also not valid - here is how it should look like:

```
{"id" : 1,"name": "name","body": "JSONstring"}


package com.mgnt.stam;

public class JsonModel {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Object body;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Object body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Here is the code that I used to check if Json String could be de-serialized into an instance of the class:

```
 try {   
    JsonModel model = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString("{\"id\" : 1,\"name\": \"name\",\"body\": \"JSONstring\"}", JsonModel.class);
    System.out.println(JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(model));
 catch(IOException ioe) {
   ....
 }
```

And it prints this: `{"id":1,"name":"name","body":"JSONstring"}` JsonUtils class is a thin wrapper over Jackson library. It is part of Open-source java library written by me. Here is a [JsonUtils Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). If you want to use the library - It is called MgntUtils and you can get it as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) with code source and Javadoc.

Comment: Do you mean that the deserialization of the json string in the body would be handled automatically?

Comment: you mentioned that I can map it to a Java POJO directly using restTemplate.exchange(url, method, null, model.class). I just took the JSON string  and the class that I posted in my answer and deserialized it using Jackson library

Comment: I updated the answer, it shows you exactly what I did